# Mouse doesn't work on xvfb

Tags: x11, xvfb, x11vnc

I am on ubuntu 18.04 (sadly, because of external considerations - EC2).

I run the following lines:

```
sudo /usr/bin/Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
/usr/local/bin/x11vnc -dp -noxdamage -geometry 1024x728 -ncache 10 -ncache_cr -viewpasswd remote_view_only_pass -passwd XXXXX  -display :0 -forever -shared -logappend /var/log/x11vnc.log -bg -noipv6
```

(Xvfb seems to be version 1.19.6)

(x11vnc: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05)

And I connect using `VNC Viewer` .

Following that, I get a mouse that seems to move , but not click. But actually the mouse position in the log (notice the `dp`) stays constant and it doesn't work.

`cursor_position: set screen pos x=512 y=364`

Comment: You probably don’t need to use sudo for the Xvfb line.  Is there a reason why you are using Xvfb + x11vnc when Xvnc would work much better?

Answer (score 0):

> Xvfb is an X server that can run on machines with no display hardware
> and no physical input devices. It emulates a dumb framebuffer using
> virtual memory.

So with Xvfb you will not get any mouse events, since physical devices are not supported.
More infos are [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xvfb)